# Calling Separate C# Classes for QA/DEV?

Tags: c#, .net, code-behind

I am working in a content management system that uses C# and allows for adding separate code in a central class. One issue that has come up is we would like to have a separate code base for QA and the rest of the site, currently we use the folder structure to switch the call from one class to the other

```
if (AssetPath == "Websites QA")
{
    InputHelperQA.Navigation();//Calling Navigation Section From Helper Class
}
else
{
    InputHelper.Navigation();
}
```

But i feel it is a very tedious way of doing this task. Is there a better way of accomplishing this?, obviously just appending InputHelper + "QA" does not work but some thing along those lines where we only have to call the method once instead of having to wrap an if else around the call.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't have separate code for different environments, besides being branches representing your environments.

You really should store your configuration in a config file or database.

Comment: Agreed but since its a cms it tends to be very flat so we only have one environment to work in but have different folders for a qa and live so that is what we are working with

Comment: now that's scary. you should have a separate environment for qa.

Answer (score 1):

You could do worse than:

1) Have an interface (which you may already have, truth be told)

```
public interface IInputHelper
{
    void Navigation();
}
```

2) Derive your two instances as you already have:

```
public class InputHelper : IInputHelper { }
public class InputHelperQA : IInputHelper { }
```

3) Create some kind of a dispatch manager:

```
public sealed class InputDispatch
{
    private Dictionary<string, IInputHelper> dispatch_ = new Dictionary<string, IInputHelper>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public InputDispatch()
    {
        dispatch_["Websites QA"] = new InputDispatchQA();
        dispatch_["Default"] = new InputDispatch();
    }

    public void Dispatch(string type)
    {
        Debug.Assert(dispatch_.ContainsKey(type));
        dispatch_[type].Navigation();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would take it one step further and use dependency injection to wire up the QA types based on a configuration setting.

Comment: @Moo-Juice that is very interesting it will take me some time to go over and digest this information can you give me an example on how i would call the dispatch manager? Also am confused on the dispatch_["Websites QA"] = new InputDispatchQA(); how does invoking the InputDispatchQA(); know which method to use. Lastly there are more methods Navigation is one of many is it possible to pass that as a variable assuming that both InputHelper and InputHelperQA have the same method ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use Dependency Injection. StructureMap (as just one example) will let you specify which concrete type to provide for an interface via a config file.

http://docs.structuremap.net/XmlConfiguration.htm